# WordPress REST API to get all media not working

Tags: media, rest-api

I am attempting to get all the media from my site [www.napkinsights.com](http://www.napkinsights.com). However, when I call https://napkinsights.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media, I am given an empty array `[]`.

How would I be able to get all my media through a REST API call?

Comment: Do you have anything in the Media library? Only attachments listed there will be returned, not every file in use on the site.

Comment: Or, are you using some sort of plugin to make it so users can only see media that they uploaded?

Comment: I'm are trying to retrieve the media (which are the napkin images, if you go to www.napkinsights.com). I just checked my media library, and all the images are there, and as for plugins-none of them conceal/hide the media.